# How do you beat the "Warrior Bash" Council challenge?

Tags: hero-academy

I can't manage to down all three warriors simultaneously. What's the solution?

[image: Warrior Bash]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to this challenge primarily involves teamwork:

1. Use the top Knight to knock the Warrior down a square.
2. Use the right Knight to knock the Warrior one square to the left.
3. Use the bottom Wizard to damage all three Warriors.
4. Use the left Archer to damage the Warrior right in front of her.
5. Drop the Inferno on all three Warriors, knocking them all out.